# Auto Indent (the = key) of C switch block

Tags: indentation, formatting, filetype-c

For the following switch block:
[image]

If I select the switch block and apply the `auto format` command, the `=` key, I get the following:

[image]

The block is formatted correctly in the first image, but it gets messed up by `auto format`.  It works fine on `if` blocks, but really messes up the case blocks.  What controls the auto-format?  Is there any way I can adjust the configuration to apply camel style brackets?

Comment: Just curious: Those braces are redundant. What benefit do they provide?

Comment: @muru There are no advantages, but it does make a difference, so depends on the code intent.  Braces control the scope, therefore make it possible to have variables local to the case with braces.  For this reason, I consistently add braces, in some cases, when local to the case variable is added, its scope is limited.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The configuration of C indenting in Vim is controlled by the `cinoptions` option. That particular aspect of indenting is controlled by the `l` (lower-case L) flag. When set to any value other than 1, it will "align with a case label instead of the statement after it in the same line."

So, you can get the indenting style you want by putting this in your `~/.vimrc` on Unix or `~/_vimrc` on Windows:

```
set cinoptions+=l1
```

See

```
:help cino-l
:help cinoptions-values
:help 'cinoption'
:help C-indenting
:help 30.2
```

Those topics are ordered roughly from particular to general aspects of C indenting.

You can find out more about auto-format here:

```
:help auto-format
```

although I don't think that's what you mean by "auto format".

Also, those `{` and `}` are called braces. Brackets are the more squarish `[` and `]`.

Comment: after doing some more digging, you are correct, this is the `auto-indent`, not `auto-format`.  A lot of VIM keyboard cheat sheets call the `=` key `auto-format`.  Anyway, the l1 option works great...